# Racket: Variable number of string arguments to system*

Tags: racket

Suppose I'm writing a wrapper function for some shell program "foo" that takes an input file, an output file and has a bunch of configuration options.

```
(define (proc in out . config)
   (system* (find-executable-path "foo") in out config))
```

This function doesn't work, because `config` doesn't evaluate to a string, it gives me `'(config1 config2 ...)`.

Converting this list to a single string doesn't work either because, if my understanding of `system*` is correct, it will be interpreted as a single argument, not several.

My question is, how can I pass each member of `config` separately to `system*`?